# How can I fetch specific text from a website which are found in a text file

Tags: python, html, web-applications

I was trying to make a small python program which would take movie names from a text file named movies.txt and would check some specified sites for the existence of those movies. I made a python file and a result page that was supposed to just show the movies that exist in the sites but instead of that it just shows all movie names from the file even if they don't exist. How could I tackle this problem?

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

app = Flask(__name__)

# Open and read file
with open('movies.txt', 'r') as f:
    movie_names = [line.strip() for line in f]

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get file
        file = request.files['file']
        
        # Read file
        movie_names = []
        for line in file:
            movie_names.append(line.strip())
        
        # Websites for movies
        movie_info = {}
        url = ['https://www.websiteone.com/', 
               'https://www.websitetwo.com', 
               'https://www.websitethree.com/', 
               'https://www.websitefour.com', 
               'https://www.websitefive.com', 
               'https://www.websitesix.com']
        for name in movie_names:
            for url in urls:
                response = requests.get(url + name)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
                info = soup.find('div', {'class': 'movie-info'})
                movie_info[name] = info.text if info else 'Not found'
        
        return render_template('result.html', movie_info=movie_info)
        
    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

result.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Movie Information</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Movie Information</h1>
    {% if movie_info %}
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Movie Name</th>
                <th>Website</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for name, website in movie_info.items() %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ name }}</td>
                <td>{{ website }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {% else %}
    <p>No movie found.</p>
    {% endif %}
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `{% if movie_info %} ...` The thing is, `movie_info` is a non-empty array even if a movie is not found, and so the if statement will evaluate to true.

Comment: How would I go to fix that?